# How to filter the data in an SQL DDL based on another DDL?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to make a simple ASP.NET C# application that will provide the user with two DDLs. The first one is pre-populated with customers from an SQL database, and when a customer is selected, the second will then populate with that customer's orders.

I am using SqlDataSources for this, the first DDL lists without issue, and displays customer names alphabetically, along with assigning the CustomerID as the value. How could I go about using code to dynamically adjust the WHERE clause of the second DDL to dynamically match the value of the first DDL?

To exemplify, my second dropdown would (ideally) have a SELECT statement similar to the following:

```
SELECT [OrderID], [CustomerID] FROM [Orders] WHERE [CustomerID] = ddl1.SelectedValue
```

Unfortunately, and naturally, this throws an error, but should illustrate what I am trying to accomplish.

Making it dynamically update from this point would be easy, but I am not certain how to filter results based on an outside source.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In the context of SQL, DDL typically means Data Definition Language (a subset of SQL).  It took a minute for me to figure out that you probably mean Drop Down List.  Also, the answer will depend on if this ASP.NET application is WebForms or ASP.NET MVC - it isn't clear what you are using.

Comment: It does indeed refer to Drop Down List, and this ASP.NET application is indeed a WebForm. I'm sorry for not being more clear earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this is a webforms application - if so, what you are trying to accomplish is commonly referred to as cascading dropdown lists - here is an example of what you need:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Creating-Cascading-DropDownLists-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: The link provided wasn't the exact solution I was looking for, however the term "Cascading Dropdown Lists" helped me find exactly what I needed, and fast, so thank you!